# What is the difference between margin-left and *margin-left in css

Tags: css

The question is all in the title, but if I have a rule that says

```
#someID{
margin-left: 10px;
*margin-left: 10px;
}
```

what does the *margin-left statement do?

Comment: This is a hack which applies style only to older versions of IE

Comment: It's incredible how whenever this question comes up, *at least one person* will say "`*` is the universal selector". Guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is useful for use as a CSS hack and  Its intent is to target specific versions of IE.

The `*<property>` is used to target IE7 (and below).

This [aticle](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/) might help you for details